# Spliting an html content based on a html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

HTML:

```
<div id ="split"><p>hi one two three</p><img class ="some class" src="some src" master_src="src" master_w="318" master_h=22"><img class="some" src="src"><h1> 4 5 6</h1></div>
```

Desired output:

```
<p>hi one two three</p>
""           
<h1>4 5 6</h1>
```

How can i get this output ? I wanted a general form if there can be n images inside a div.

```
$("#split").find('img').each(function(index){
       alert($(this).splitsuchthat()) 
// for first time it should be <p>hi one two three</p>
// secon time ""
// third time <h1> 4 5 6</h1>  

});
```

Comment: this `<p>.*?<\/p>` would match the paragraph tag.

Comment: @AvinashRaj You should never use reg exp to match html

Comment: Obligatory "parse HTML, don't regex it" comment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I still have no clue what you are trying to accomplish. What does img have to do with it?

Comment: me either, he wants to split by image, but is trying to get other elements.

Comment: i want that i would get the html content before every <img> tag

Comment: anyone can give me a demo

Comment: LOL, hard to give a demo when the question was not clear. So use `prev(":not(img)")` But does not make sense that the last image does not follow the pattern of "before"

Comment: $("img").prev() or $("img").parents()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prevUntil` (or `nextUntil`) to get the element between two images.  Then you simply need to deal with the remain end:

http://jsfiddle.net/GLZaJ/1/

```
// a helper function to print the html of elements contained in a jquery object
function toHtmlString($els){
    var clone = $els.clone();

    return $('<div>').append(clone).html();
}

// get all elements before an image
$("#split > img").each(function(index){
    var $prevs = $(this).prevUntil("img");
    var htmlString = toHtmlString($prevs);
    alert(htmlString);
});

// get everything after the last image
var $after = $("#split > img:last").nextAll();
var htmlString = toHtmlString($after);
alert(htmlString);
```

Comment: thanks can i use the $(temp).find('img') since temp is storing the div id

Comment: `$(temp).children("img")` is probably slightly better as images within nested elements won't work right.

Comment: if i am using childern the  each loop is not executing (it is not going inside for loop in my code)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand your question but here is maybe what you need:

```
$(function(){
    $("#split>*").each(function(index){
                     alert($(this).text()) ;
                     });

});
```

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/9Z5Mt/